# Running Jetty web server in LAN

Tags: java, google-app-engine, webserver

GAE comes with an inbuilt jetty webserver for testing purpose.Can it be configured to accessed within our LAN?

I can access it using **http://localhost:8888**  or **http://127.0.0.1:8888**  but can't access using **http://192.168.1.201:8888**  (This my local LAN ip)

why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

To make your GAE accessible on your LAN, you have to configure the launcher to use the address 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

Open the GoogleAppEngineLauncher >> Application Settings for your app

Add “-a 0.0.0.0″ to the Extra Flags section and restart. Now your GAE will run in your LAN and can be accessed by other devices.

Comment: It seems this is for python SDK. I am using java SDK on eclipse. Can you tell me how to do that on it?

Comment: Same procedure - only for the GAE-plugin of eclipse: Eclipse >>> Package Explorer >>> Right click on project >>> Run As >>> Run Configurations >>> Arguments >>> add "-a 0.0.0.0" to the program arguments >>> Apply >>> close ---- And the solution above also works for JAVA, if you use the AppEngineLauncher (you have to, if you work with Netbeans - only for eclipse there is a plugin as far as I know)

Comment: When i open the setting dialog it show --port=8888 -a C:\Workspace\project1\war. Tried to add -a 0.0.0.0 after this. It give error and show parameter help at consol. Again tried to add it to new line. Same error

Comment: you have to add it to the "Arguments", not into the --port / you can also set your IP instead of 0.0.0.0 to make the server bind to only one IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure GAE to listen on all interfaces, not only localhost's loopback interface (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Can you give me some idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ IDEA users (version 11 at least):

If you're using the GAE plugin and have a AppEngine Run configuration, open its settings and add to Server parameters: `-a 0.0.0.0`. This will make the GAE built-in Jetty server to listen on your lan/wlan ip address, http://10.0.1.2 for instance.